# using queue to add a shape in canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was confused on how to add a shape using a queue in canvas. I'm trying to add a triangle. This is the code I've got. I'm getting an error >>> AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'enqueue'

I've been trying this for awhile now and I thought I had the right idea, I just need some guidelines thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
from queue import *



class Queue:
  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []
  def is_empty(self):
    return self.items == []
  def size(self):
    return len(self.items)
  def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.insert(0, item)
  def dequeue(self):
    return self.items.pop(0)
  def peek(self):
    return self.items[0]


class Recta():
  def __init__(self, height=60, width=80): 
    self.queue = Queue()  

def create_buttons(self):
    self.button5 = Button(self.frame, text = "Add Arc", command = self.random_arc)
    self.button5.pack(side = 'left')    

def random_arc(self):
    w = random.randrange(45)
    h = random.randrange(90)
    self.queue.enqueue(self.canvas.create_arc(0,w,h,fill= "green"))

tes = Recta()
tes = Queue()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Those parameters x and y: Aren't they really w and h?

Comment: yeah they are ill change them sorry for confusion

Comment: also, in your case "create_arc" is called like this: create_arc(0,0,w,h,fill="green")  This solves the error you mentioned in the comments below:  error >>> _tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 3

Comment: still, something is missing: Is this your complete code? self.canvas for example can't really work that way...

Comment: Oh I see thanks ! I always thought it had to be 3 because its like a triangle. Thanks for the help !

Comment: no its not the complete code i still have to make a function to remove the arc aswell

Comment: you know how you imported queue without having to have a queue class, how would you do the same for stack ()??

Comment: [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) shows the use of **lists as stack** using **.append()** and **.pop()** Just search for "stack" on the page.

Comment: But if I had to create a stack such as s = Stack() wouldn't it come up with an error ? because i don't have the stack class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the module [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) I don't see a function enqueue().

There is `queue.Queue.put()`, though.

**Update**

Is it possible, that python is taking the "wrong" `Queue`, meaning the one from inside the module queue?

**Update**

Maybe start by renaming your class "Queue" to something different like "Queue1".

Or just use the **`queue.Queue`** from the module.

**Update**

If you want to use a stack, just use `list` funcitonalities, no class Stack is necessary:

```
stack = list()
stack.append('item1')
stack.append('item2')
stack.append('item3')
print stack.pop()
>>> 'item3'
```

By just using `.pop()` you make it appear to be a stack.

Comment: isn't this the enque function def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.insert(0, item)

Comment: The type of self.queue is not your self defined class Queue, but queue.Queue, i think. And queue.Queue does not provide a function called enqueue(...), only put(...).

Comment: this is the line: **self.queue = Queue()**

Comment: So how should I fix that so I am able to use enqueue ?

Comment: Either delete the line from queue import * because you don't use Queue from this module or rename your class Queue to something else, e.g. QueueTest.

Comment: okay If I deleted queue import * , what would replace this in order to be able to enqueue the triangle onto the queue()

Comment: another way is to use self.queue = queue.Queue() (without using your class Queue but keeping from queue import *) and replace self.queue.enqueue(...) by self.queue.put(...)

Comment: when I do that I get this error >>> self.queue = queue.Queue()
NameError: name 'queue' is not defined

Comment: Now add **import queue**.

Comment: Yup when I do that it seems alright. I uploaded another piece of code I forgot to add which has buttons. When i click add arc it seems to give me this error >>> _tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 3